# How do i sync serial communication to an arduino to the vertical refresh of a tablet?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to synchronize serial communication (via bluetooth) between an android tablet (Android 6.0 Marshmallow) and an arduino (Mega 2560) to the vertical refresh of the tablet. I've been using Choreographer (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer) to control the timing of the display update but the serial communication is not synced to the display update (and it's variable).

Does anyone have any idea how to make this work? I've included the relevant segment of android code from my app.

```
public void armVSyncHandler() {
    if(!frameCallbackPending) {
        frameCallbackPending = true;
        if(frameCallback == null)
        {
            frameCallback = new Choreographer.FrameCallback() {
                @Override
                public void doFrame(long frameTimeNanos) {
                    frameCallbackPending = false;

                    if (blackView.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                        blackView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        blackView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    armVSyncStrobe();                    
                }
            };
        }
        Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(frameCallback);
    }
}

public void armVSyncStrobe() {
    if(!frameCallbackPendingS) {
        frameCallbackPendingS = true;
        if (frameCallbackS == null)
        {
            frameCallbackS = new Choreographer.FrameCallback() {
                @Override
                public void doFrame(long frameTimeNanos) {
                    frameCallbackPendingS = false;

                    String strobe = getBinaryTime();
                    try {
                        sendData(strobe);
                        Log.d(TAG,"data sent");
                        timeRecordDb.insertData(strobe, "receive: "+tvReceived.getText());
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "data not sent");
                    }
                }
            };
        }
        Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(frameCallbackS);
    }
}

 public void sendData(String msg) throws IOException
    {
    try {
        mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {}

    msg += "\n";
    mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
}
```